# Bash script with (X)dialog asking for root password (kdesu substitute)

Tags: password, su, dialog

I'm using (X)dialog for a script that a normal runs, but it needs root privileges for some commands. The script runs from a .desktop file, thus the user sees no terminal. For example here

```
#!/bin/bash
Xdialog --msgbox "Welcome" 0 0
touch /root/testfile
Xdialog --msgbox "All OK" 0 0
```

the `touch` command does not execute. One solution would be to use `kdesu`

```
kdesu touch /root/testfile
```

but this approach has two problems: the user has to provide the password for every command and the window of kdesu does not follow the same theme as the rest of the windows.

Note that I want the user to provide the root password and not being a sudoer.

I have found a similar script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15586177/3258891), but I cannot apply it on my script, as the actual command cannot accept the password as the `sshpass` does.

Comment: Are you opposed to using `sudo`?

Comment: Yes, user should provide the root password, not his own.

Comment: You have 3 choices: 1. Convert your script to ncurses, and get rid of X, and use `su` as intended, 2. keep the X integration and use `sudo` with his own password. 3. Convert your script to an actual UI, and use themes.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this would be to just execute `su` at the beginning of the script. The user enter the root password only once at the beginning of the script. You can then execute commands without root privileges by doing `su [username] -c [your command not to be executed with root privileges]`.

However, you can't use dialog boxes to ask for the password here.